# Exclude Saturday and Sunday from a range of dates in JQL on Jira Server

Tags: jira, jql

I have this query

```
project = "xyz" AND due > startOfDay() AND due = startOfDay(3d)
```

What this does is , it gives me the issues where there are exactly 3 days remaining until the due date from today.

i.e if I have a ticket which has a due date of 10th July 2023 and today is 7th July 2023, the issue should show up.

Now from the 7th July to 10th July , there are weekends 8th and 9th July ( Sat and Sun).

Currently what the JQL is giving is including the weekends.

I want the JQL to exclude it.

Expected result: If the due date was on 10th July, it should give me the result when today was 5th of July.

How do I achieve this with JQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your due date is less than 7 days away, you can use the following JQL for a due date three business days from now:

```
(duedate < startOfWeek(1) AND duedate = startofday(3d) ) 
OR  (duedate > startOfWeek(1) AND duedate = startofday(5d))
```

If you want to check for a due date five business days from now you can use:

```
(duedate < startOfWeek(1) AND duedate = startofday(5d) ) 
OR  (duedate > startOfWeek(1) AND duedate = startofday(7d))
```

The top line checks a due date before the weekend. The second line checks a due date next week and adds two days for the weekend. If the due date is more than 7 days away, you will need to adjust the numbers by adding 2 days for each weekend you know for sure will be between now and the due date.

If you want to check for a due date ten business days from now, you have for sure one and maybe two weekends before the due date. You can use:

```
(duedate < startOfWeek(2) AND duedate = startofday(12d) ) 
OR  (duedate > startOfWeek(2) AND duedate = startofday(14d))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it does not work.
Today is 13th July and I set the due date on 20th July ( 7 days including weekends ), 24th July ( 7 days excluding weekends ), no luck, the issue does not show up in search.

Comment: I have clarified my answer. I also verified the code on a test project. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hello, there is a small bug in the first query, the 3 business days one.
If I run the query on Saturday which is 22nd July and the due date is 27th July which is a Thursday.
The first clause will fail (duedate < startOfWeek(1) AND duedate = startofday(3d) because the the startofweek will be Sunday the next day after Saturday and then the (duedate > startOfWeek(1) AND duedate = startofday(5d) will run which will pass as 27th July is 5 days from 22nd July but the due date more than 3 business days. Just want to highlight this